# How to get the RowIndex of SecondPage in GridView

Tags: vb.net, gridview, page-index-changed

How to get the RowIndex of SecondPage in GridView in **PageIndexChanged.**

I have set **AllowPaging="true"** and **PageSize="10"**

So that the second row of second page of Grid should return the rowindex as 11.

Keeping in Mind the first row number of first page of grid is 0.

I know how to take the page index of first page but need to know how to take second page rowindex in the PageIndexChanged Event.

Comment: http://cloudfour.com/examples/mediaqueries/image-test/#t5

Answer (score 0):

Use PageIndex property of GridView:

```
Sub MyGridView_PageIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim currentPage As Integer = MyGridView.PageIndex


    ' Do something with page

  End Sub
```